# Is the exact same sound clip used in A New Hope and The Force Awakens?

Tags: dialogue, star-wars, the-force-awakens, sound-effects, a-new-hope

I have seen The Force Awakens twice now. And I swear that there is a scene where the storm troopers say something along the lines of.

> They are splitting up.. we think they are on Level 5 and 6

Or something along those lines.

My memory is pretty bad but I feel like some storm troopers say the same thing In A New Hope when they are on the death star.

My question is.

Is the line said in both movies? If yes, is it the same sound clip?

Comment: when I saw the most recent movie, I heard it and assumed it was an inside wink, considering how much was lifted from the first movie.

Comment: Can you clafify just where in the film you think you saw this? I checked WGA script and nothing like that *seems* to be said in the entire script

Comment: Also, I don't remember that phrase in ANH, and couldn't find it in the script I have either.

Comment: Ill hunt it down.

Comment: 1hr 25 min 40 secs ish "we think they are splitting they may be on level 5 and 6". From a co workers dvd rip he had on an ipad in ANH i couldn't find a clip on youtube. I am seeing the movie again on sat I will listen for it then.

Comment: @DVK forgot to tag you in the above.

Comment: I had a vague feeling like this too when watching TFA.  Someone tag me in if an answer appears.

Comment: @AndrewWhatever as requested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is the same sound bite. The exact quote in ANH is, "We Think They May Be Splitting Up. They May Be On Level 5 And 6 Now, Sir." At least the first part is in both ANH and TFA.

https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-find?text=We%20Think%20They%20May%20Be%20Splitting%20Up

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).